# How to store and retrieve base64 encoded image in Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am sending an image in `base64` format in a `json` message

`image:["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...","data:image/png;base64,idfsd..."]`

I want to store this image in `Cassandra`. This `json` maps to my model as an `Array[String]` -

```
case class ImageArray(
image: Array[String]
}
```

I have read that to store images in cassandra, I need ByteBuffer. So I use ByteBuffer.wrap() to convert the array different indexes of the array into ByteBuffer.

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(model.image(0).getBytes()) //for the moment, I am taking only 1 image
```

I am unable to figure out how to conovert the `ByteBuffer` back into a `String`. I can retrieve the bytes from `Cassandra` like follows

```
(row.getBytes("image"))
```

The above gives me a `ByteBuffer`. How do I convert this into a `String` which I could use later to create an `Array[String]`

Comment: I have done `Array((row.getBytes("image")).asCharBuffer().toString)`. Does this look OK? I am concerned whether the conversion might be incorrect due to use of different character encoding. I suppose not as I am doing encoding and decoding on the same platform (server side)

Answer (score 0):

Though I was able to solve it, the method was very slow so I dropped the idea of storing images as bytes and kept them as string (base64) as that is what I am getting from the server.

Coming to the original issue, to solve the problem, I made a few changes.

Changed Array to List in the model as Cassandra understand Lists

```
case class ImageArray(
image: List[String]
}
```

The json array or images mapped to image list by creating a custom `Reads` -  `(JsPath \ "image").read[List[String]]`

In `cassandra`, the table schema for storing the image arrays was `image list<blob>,`

Once I had the List in the model, I converted it into `List` of `String` into `List` of `Byte` using `.value("image",seqAsJavaList(((ByteBuffer.wrap(model.image(0).getBytes())).array().toList):::((ByteBuffer.wrap(model.image(1).getBytes())).array().toList)))`

Above, I took the first element of image list (a string which is base64 representation of image at index 0), convert it into byte using `ByteBuffer.wrap`, then converted `ByteBuffer` to `Array` and then converted it to `List`. This gave  me `List[Byte]` for 1st image. I repeat it for image(1) and then join the two images using `:::`. Then I convert this `Scala` `List` to `Java` using `seqAsJavaList`.

Note: As the above method required multiple conversions, it isn't a optimal way. I instead decided to store the image as List[String]