# unable to convert a String array into blob in Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am sending an image in `base64` format in a `json` message. I want to store the image in `Cassandra`. The corresponding column in Cassandra is ``image list`

The image data in json is

`image:["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...","data:image/png;base64,idfsd..."]`

This json maps to my model as an Array[String] -

The model class which maps to the json is

```
case class PracticeQuestion (id: Option[UUID],
                              d: String,
                               h: List[String],
                               image: Array[String],//images maps here
                              s: String,
                               f: String,
                               t: Set[String],
                              title: String,
                              a:String,
                               r:List[String])
```

I have read that to store images in cassandra, I need ByteBuffer. So I use ByteBuffer.wrap() to convert the array different indexes of the array into ByteBuffer. But my `insert` statement is failing. The `Datastax` error is

The I am trying to convert the `Array[String]` to `list<blob>` is

```
.value("image",seqAsJavaList(Seq[ByteBuffer](ByteBuffer.wrap(model.image(0).getBytes())))) 
 //for the moment, I am taking only 1 image
```

I take the first image, get its bytes, create a `BytesBuffer`. The I convert the `BytesBuffer` into a `Seq` and then the `Seq` into Java `List`

The error I see is `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value 6 of type class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon does not correspond to any CQL3 type`

the complete insert command is

```
QueryBuilder.insertInto(tableName).value("id",model.id.get)           .value("answer",model.a)
      .value("d",model.d)
      .value("f",model.f)
      .value("h",seqAsJavaList(model.h)) 
      .value("image",seqAsJavaList(Seq[ByteBuffer](ByteBuffer.wrap(model.image(0).getBytes())))) 
      .value("r",model.r)
      .value("s",model.s)
      .value("t",setAsJavaSet(model.t))
      .value("title",model.title)
      .ifNotExists();
```

The database schema is

```
id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    a text,
    d text,
    f text,
    h list<text>,
    image list<blob>,
    r list<text>,
    s text,
    t set<text>,
    title text
```

Comment: this can be closed. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844961/how-to-store-and-retrieve-base64-encoded-image-in-cassandra